# Distance group NSFetchedResultsController sections

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, core-data

I'm using Core Data for a tableview. My data is ordered by the distance from your current location. What I'd like is to have a new section for items with 5, 10 and 20 miles.

My distance value is stored in the data store as an NSInteger and I get it out using a NSNumber in my object model.

I've done a bit of searching around and found that I need to use the `sectionNameKeyPath` attribute to make the data sectioned.

My problem is that I don't know the best way to group the data. During my searches I came across either a transient property or using a category of NSNumber to work out which section the item should be in.

Are either of these methods the best way of getting my end result, if so, can anyone provide any details on how to implement it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a derived attribute to the object (it's not strictly needed in the model), let's name it `range`.   I'd make it a read only property, you can cache the value or not.

When it's 0-5, return 5, 5.x - 10 return 10, etc.

Then set `range` as your `sectionNameKeyPath`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Sorry if I'm being a bit dumb here, but when you say a "derived attribute" do you mean in my data model object .h file, I do something like: @property (monatomic, readonly) NSInteger * range; Also, would I need to create my own getter method to return either 5, 10 or 20?

Comment: This method will work but its a quick and dirty fix that muddles the UI and model together. As a rule, you don't want to contaminate you model layer with the implementation details of the view layer. What happens if you have several tableviews all with sections defined by ranges of different attributes? Are you going to have multiple derived attributes, one for each tableview. What happens when you want to use the data model in another app? It is best practice to keep the model and view as separate as possible.

Comment: scrooby, yes.  @TechZen, agreed.  But do you have a better way to manage this while still using the FetchedResultsController?  I'd love to know about it (for exactly the reasons you state).   - - - The "clean design" option right now is to implement all the delegate methods yourself, throw away FetchedResultsController and only use FetchedResults - it's a lot more work to get the "clean design", scrooby you're in the position to decide which is desired.  As TechZen said, if there are a lot of possibilities you may not want it pushing into the model.

Comment: hmmm, looks like I'm going to have to put up or shutup.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a highly customized section behavior, you need to subclass NSFetchedResultsController to give you the behavior you want. See the NSFetchedResultsController class docs for details.

You will need to subclass in this case because your not looking at a single ordered attribute like the alphabetized first letter of a string attribute but rather a range in which each attribute falls into.

This is a cleaner solution than altering the data model because you can use it to display the data many different ways in many different tableviews without having to muddy up your data model.

Comment: Thanks for you comment, do you know of any good examples of subclassing NSFetchedResultsController? The Apple docs did mention which methods you could subclass, but I couldn't see any examples.

Comment: Sorry, these are always so custom that I don't think people do many examples. I'm not sure myself how to implement what you want. Let me think about it.